# Include global partial from a Symfony 1.4 plugin

Tags: plugins, view, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to include a global partial from a Symfony 1.4 plugin from within a module? If so, how?

I know one can include a partial from a module from a plugin, but how to include a global template?

So suppose my Symfony application has the following file structure.

```
/config
/lib
/apps
  /backend
    /config
    /modules
      /aModule
        /config
        /templates
          /aTemplateWithinAModule.php
        /actions
          /actions.class.php
    /templates
/plugins
  /examplePlugin
    /lib
    /config
    /modules
    /templates
      /_aGlobalPluginPartial.php
```

How can I include the 'aGlobalPluginPartial' from within aTemplateWithinAModule.php?

I have tried:

- `include_partial('global/aGlobalPluginPartial')`
- `include_partial('examplePlugin/global/aGlobalPluginPartial')`
- `include_partial('examplePlugin/aGlobalPluginPartial')`

So far none of the above work.

My plugin is enabled in the project configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put it in a module.

```
/plugins
  /examplePlugin
    /lib
    /config
    /modules
      /example
        /templates
          /_aGlobalPluginPartial.php
```

And then include it using:

```
include_partial('example/aGlobalPluginPartial');
```

Do not forget to enable the module `example` in your `settings.yml` file (in `enabled_modules`).

Comment: I know. But I don't want to. I want to include a global partial. Or is that not possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. When I want to include a *global* partial I put them in a default module, like `main` and call them from here.